# MySQL function returns wrong value on repeat, when it contains window functions

Tags: mysql, functions, window-functions

MySQL 8.0.33

I have a stored function to calculate the sum of all time gaps in a series of events on a given day. This function uses a window function LEAD(...) OVER() to determine the gap between the end of one event and the start of the next event.

If I run the query itself multiple times, the result is always the same. If use the function, the first execution has the correct value, and the rest return NULL.

Why???

**Edit:**

I have corrected some errors in the code in the block below and made an [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7gVHyFnvwVnrLJz6gVFMz8/0).

Now my question has changed to: "Why does this work correctly in the Fiddle, but not on my machine? What setting can affect this?"

**Edit 2:**

Adding `FLUSH TABLES events;` between the two function calls fixes the issue on my server. Again, why is this happening?

---

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `start` (`start`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `events` (`id`, `start`, `end`) VALUES
(1, '2023-02-06 08:14:00', '2023-02-06 10:30:00'),
(2, '2023-02-06 11:57:00', '2023-02-06 12:25:00'),
(3, '2023-02-06 14:00:00', '2023-02-06 14:15:00'),
(4, '2023-02-06 15:00:00', '2023-02-06 16:49:00');


CREATE FUNCTION fx_timegap (dt DATE)
RETURNS DECIMAL(4,2) NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA
RETURN (
    WITH
    C1 AS (
        SELECT
            (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LEAD(start) OVER (ORDER BY start ASC)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end)) / 3600 AS gap
        FROM events
        WHERE DATE(start) = dt
    )
    SELECT SUM(gap)
    FROM C1
);
```

This works:

```
WITH
C1 AS (
    SELECT
        (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LEAD(start) OVER (ORDER BY start ASC)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end)) / 3600 AS gap
    FROM events
    WHERE DATE(start) = '2023-02-06'
)
SELECT SUM(gap)
FROM C1;

>>> 3.7833


WITH
C1 AS (
    SELECT
        (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LEAD(start) OVER (ORDER BY start ASC)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end)) / 3600 AS gap
    FROM events
    WHERE DATE(start) = '2023-02-06'
)
SELECT SUM(gap)
FROM C1;

>>> 3.7833
```

This doesn't:

```
SELECT fx_timegap('2023-02-06');

>>> 3.78


SELECT fx_timegap('2023-02-06');

>>> NULL
```

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5.

Comment: Are all of the values in the `start` field unique or are there any duplicates?

Comment: @Akina I have updated the post.

Comment: @J.D. Unique and unchanged during query execution.

Comment: Not reproduced. https://dbfiddle.uk/KK2J9j0F

Comment: @Akina Yeah, I already said that. The question is why the behavior changes?

Comment: This is an effect of some code which is not provided. We cannot predict the source of your issue.

Comment: There is no other code. I am running the same exact queries in the same order directly. It might have to do with some server setting, but  not one I am applying directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problems see in:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=110983
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=110847

If you have more information, please write.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So, it's a bug in the server, confirmed by the developers. I have accepted your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Return a value, not a `SELECT`.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION fx_timegap (_dt DATE)
RETURNS DECIMAL(4,2) NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE _res DECIMAL(4,2);
    WITH C1 AS (
        SELECT
            (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LEAD(start) OVER (ORDER BY start ASC)) -
             UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end)) / 3600 AS gap
        FROM se326488
        WHERE DATE(start) = _dt
    )
    SELECT SUM(gap)  INTO _res  FROM C1;
    RETURN _res;
END //
DELIMITER ;

SELECT fx_timegap('2023-02-06');
SELECT fx_timegap('2023-02-06');
```

Comment: No difference. SELECT returns the rowset which can be converted to scalar value.

Comment: @Akina - Well, it worked for me, so I don't know what their problem is.